# Pointer Arithmetics and casting

Tags: c++

Somehow these pointer arithmetics are very confusing to me.
An example:

```
uint16_t *a = (uint16_t *)0x200;
a += 4 * sizeof(uint32_t);
```

When calculating the new value of a, what is your thought process?

This is how I am trying to figure it out:

1. The pointer (a) points to an address, which has a value of 0x200 of uint16_t type.
2. The second operation moves the pointer a to a + 4 * 8 bytes to a location 32 bytes (20 in hex) further up, which is apparently 0x220. How come this is not &a + 32?  I think this is where I confuse things... Why is the pointer pointing to 0x200 and not &a?

Comment: Choose between `C++` and `C`. They are different, so please tag your question with only one of them.

Comment: I thought in this case it was valid in both languages...I guess I'll just stick c++ in there.

Comment: The compiler already knows how to do pointer arithmetic. You don't need to help it out. `a += 4` will increment the pointer to the fourth `uint16_t`.

Comment: `&a` is the address *of* `a`, not the address stored *in* `a`.

Comment: Thanks for all the comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pointer arithmetic is in units of the type being pointed to.

So if you just did `++a;`, the new value of `a` would be `0x202`, *not* `0x201`.

So, when you add `4 * sizeof (uint32_t)`, that is the same as adding `2 * 4 * 4`, i.e. 32, which is hex `0x20`. So the new value is `0x220`.

Comment: Thank you. This was exactly the answer I was looking for.